# Flask doesn't see environment variables

Tags: python, apache, flask, environment-variables, virtualenv

I connected apache with my Flask App with WSGI with virtualenv.I have a couple configuration variables(secret key and database URI), so I'm using

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('CONFIG_FILE_FLASK')
```

The error in apache errorlog is:

> RuntimeError: The environment variable 'CONFIG_FILE_FLASK' is not set and as such configuration could not be loaded.  Set this variable and make it point to a configuration file

This variable exists (using command **printenv**) :

```
......
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
COLORTERM=truecolor
CONFIG_FILE_FLASK=/var/flaskconf/config.cfg

SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/oleg
USER=oleg
......
```

**/var/flaskconf/config.cfg** itself is :

```
SECRET_KEY = 'thisissupposedtobesecret'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/Table'
```

It also doesn't work if I do this:

```
sudo python __init__.py
```

**BUT**, if without sudo it works!(maybe it'll be a clue)

Thank you so much in advance.
Ready to provide any file immediately.

**UPDATE 1**
I also noticed that variable FLASK_APP also "invisible"

```
oleg@test:/var/www/app/app$ export FLASK_APP=app.py
oleg@test:/var/www/app/app$ flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (app) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
oleg@test:/var/www/app/app$
```

Any ideas about that?

EDIT:
**File structure:**

[image]

Comment: Environment variables must be set for the user that your app is running under, and active for that session. sudo changes your user to root for the command and root doesn't have that variable set.

Comment: @Josh J 
apache running under user "oleg", environment variables set up for "oleg".
I understand why *sudo...* not working, thanks. But what's wrong with apache?

Comment: Depending on the arguments you are using `sudo` will strip off your environment or not.

Comment: @JoshJ is right. However in this case, Apache reads system environment variables and passes it as a dict to the WSGIHandler all the while running the application as a process in it's own process group. [This is old](https://gist.github.com/GrahamDumpleton/b380652b768e81a7f60c) but may help give you an idea about how to fix this

Comment: Is app.py in that app directory or is the structure app/__init__.py. Your earlier example seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you, I've been there. Tried to do this but it wasn't working correctly, so there is not a way to fix that.

Comment: @JoshJ I will attach the structure of directories to my post.

Comment: FLASK_APP should either be a module name on your Python path, or the full path/file of the .py file to run. You are mixing both. Your module is app but the file is in app/__init__.py. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved by making my Flask application a python module.

First of all the structure of application now is next (correct structure):

[image]

And the `__init__.py` includes following:

```
from .iotdev import app
```

Also to work with the virtual environment, site configuration file was edited by adding `WSGIDaemonProcess` AND `WSGIProcessGroup` statement, so the iotdev.conf(the full path to file is **/etc/apache2/sites-available/iotdev.conf**):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com  
    WSGIDaemonProcess iotdev python-path=/var/www/iotdev:/var/www/iotdev/iotdev/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup iotdev
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/iotdev/iotdev.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/iotdev/iotdev/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/iotdev/iotdev/static
    <Directory /var/www/iotdev/iotdev/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Thanks everybody who was helping me with this issue, you're pushed me to some thoughts and ideas that make this working.**